# Flutter runs indefinitely in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to run a sample project with Android Studio and Flutter, but when I use flutter-run, it keeps running with the same message.

["Starting a Gradle Daemon, x busy Daemon..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCdKJ.png)

```
[ +781 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[+121189 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120798 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120700 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120797 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 4 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120701 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 5 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120799 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 6 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120697 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 7 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120700 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 8 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120801 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 9 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120900 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 10 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120800 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 11 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120795 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 13 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120804 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 15 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120798 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 17 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+120902 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 19 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

I have tried reinstalling Flutter and Android Studio without any luck, also waited around 2 hours to finish but it never did. Furthermore, [Flutter doctor doesn't detect any problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP8p8.png)

I am using Android Studio v4, the latest build of Flutter (1.17.5), and a Pixel 3 for simulation, but I don't have experience with Android Studio so it's unknown to me if it's problem on the configuration or something Flutter related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the antivirus (Eset) firewall was blocking the Gradle Daemon. Once I created a rule for the ports 20000-60000 (which are the most common for Android) in Interactive mode, it went without problems. I hope this will be helpful to someone else with the same issue :)

Reference: https://qiita.com/kmatae/items/8f898180408bc3a04c9a  (in Japanese)